# Floating column problem

Tags: html, css

On my test site - http://dev.nerdysyntax.com/index.html - I am trying to float three columns towards the bottom of this page under "what can I do for you." The columns seem to be having a padding or margin problem. No matter which width I change or the number I change the margin-right or padding-right, the third column seems to fall to the next line before it completely pushes right.

As you can see in on the page, there is a lot of space from the end of the third column to the end of my page width. Tried different things, but can't figure out the issue. Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
.item {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 48px;
    width: 30%;
}

.item:first-child {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
```

**Edit**

When you say breaks, I take it you mean last `.item` drops down a level. This is because your parent container has a fixed width, the children elements combined must not exceed it.

When floating : `real width = width + padding + margin`

Comment: Yep that works thanks. Kind of confused at why it breaks so early. Can you explain why this method works over just using a margin or padding? I've looked in over scripts using firebug and haven't seen this method, which works.

Comment: Update answer after comment. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning all the ins and outs of css. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the .item property in your css:

```
.item {
float: left;
font-size: 18px;
margin: 15px 32px 0px 0;
width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: If you look at your columns on the bottom they don't line up with the ones up top -- try changing the width to 33%.

Comment: Oh is that what it is. The method above from stacks work. I tried the method you are using previously and it still drops the column to the next row.

Answer (score 1):

You mix pixels and percentages. Every ".item" element has right margin (32px) but you need right margin only for first and second element. When you give 5% for first and second right margin you have 90% for blocks.
Try it:

```
.item{width:30%; margin-right:5%}
.item:last-child{margin-right:0}
```

Comment: Yea that's why it's good I have you guys to tell me when I'm making rookie mistakes like mixing pixels and percentages. Didn't know you shouldn't do that. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can mix pixels and percentages but *only* when you know how much pixels takes one percentage or when you are sure that you won't have any problems because of that. In this case it all comes down to calculate if all dimensions won't take more than 100% of width. In that case it's easier to use only percentages beacause it's not "pixel-perfect" design.